# Can we define an attribute for a class that is applied to all instances of that class?

Tags: c#, attributes

I want to create a class that is always ignored during serialization. Normally, you can tell a serializer to ignore a certain property using the `[IgnoreDataMember()]` attribute, but I would like to set up the class itself so that there's no chance of it being used without that attribute.

For instance, rather than having the following:

```
internal class MyInternalClass<T> { ... }

public class Dog : Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember()]
    public MyInternalClass<int> Walks { get; set; }
}
public class Cat : Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember()]
    public MyInternalClass<double> Pats { get; set; }
}
public class Bird : Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //I don't have any MyInternalClass instances
}
//... + a dozen other classes with or without one of those properties
```

I could simply have

```
[IgnoreDataMember()]
internal class MyInternalClass<T> { ... }

public class Dog : Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyInternalClass<int> Walks { get; set; }
}
public class Cat : Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyInternalClass<double> Pets { get; set; }
}
public class Bird : Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //I don't have any MyInternalClass instances
}
//...
```

And the attribute would automatically be applied to all instances.

The above doesn't work of course, because `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute` is a property attribute, not a class attribute. Is there any way to solve this (maybe with a class attribute that can apply some attribute to all property instances? eg:

```
[AutoPropertyAttribute( typeof(IgnoreDataMemberAttribute), attribParams: null )]
internal class MyInternalClass<T> { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think there is one... Maybe something like `DataContractSerializerSettings.DataContractSurrogate` would work to replace it with another type?